# Can I create my own command in python?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

Suppose I have command like **cd abc/def**, So I want to create own command like '**a**'.

If I run 'a' command it ,should run command cd abc/def

```
optiplex-3020:~$ a
```

So could it be possible and I want to use python as scripting language

Comment: Do you want to change the working dir in the parent process (the shell) from within your program? That's (generally) not possible.

Comment: @mrc02_kr this question may be a duplicate, but not of the one you're pointing to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd` is a built-in command and cannot be run by an external program, so you must use your shell:

```
alias a='cd abc/def'
```

If you want this to be permanent, put it in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` depending on your shell.

Comment: It is giving me the error,$ bash: alias: a: not found
$bash: alias: =: not found
$bash: alias: cd abc/def/ab: not found

Comment: I removed spaces it works for me thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just use aliases in linux it does exactly what you want.
Other option is to create alias that points to the python script, but i see no point using python when you have it integrated in linux.